# how to get validated data from serializers to views in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am returning some data from def create method in seriaizers.py file I want to acccess that data in views.py I dont know how to get it.
serilizers.py

```
def create(self, validated_data):
      //returning something
      return validated_data
```

views.py

```
if serializer.is_valid():
     serializer.save()
     //I want to return that validated_data here so how to get it here here
      Response(validated_data)
```

Comment: use ```serializer.data```

Answer (score 1):

To get the validated data, use `serializer.validated_data`. See the [Deserializing Objects](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects) section of the manual.

Also, I want to point out a potential footgun here: you're supposed to return a model instance, from the create() method, rather than the validated data.